# Django raw SQL query - looping over result, it executes a query for every iteration

Tags: sql, django

Been writing some raw SQL queries after noticing how inefficient some of Django's built-in queries were. I'm trying to loop through the `QuerySet` result and group them into categories (I'm aware of the `regroup` template tag, this doesn't work for me - I need to be able to access the separate groups independently). Here's my code:

```
m = Media.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM table') # query simplified for sake of example

media_items = {'aim-icons' : [], 'banners' : [], 'hi-res-photos' : [], 'photos' : [], 'print-ads' : [], 'videos' : [], 'wallpapers' : [] }

for item in m:
    media_items[item.type_slug].append(item)
```

This gives me what I want (eg a list that I can access like `media_items['wallpapers']`) but it runs a database query for every iteration to fetch the `type_slug` field. I tried adding `m = list(m)` before the loop, no effect.

Can anyone help me out here? This seems like it should be simple.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What kind of inefficient queries are you seeing generated? Are you sure you're not asking Django for the information in the wrong way?

Comment: It's possible I am, but basically my app has a lot of foreign keys so I guess it's querying in ways it doesn't always need to. I've tried using `select_related` and had some success, but in this particular case a raw query was the most efficient, in terms of # of DB hits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

The issue breaks down here to how Django's `raw()` method works. It returns model instances (which had properties you were accessing, resulting in the extra query).

The proper tools here are `connection.cursor()`, `cursor.execute()` and `cursor.fetchall()`. Here's the example from the docs:

```
def my_custom_sql():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data modifying operation - commit required
    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

    # Data retrieval operation - no commit required
    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Well, the extra queries being generated are to fetch the `type_slug`, but it's definitely included in my `SELECT`. I just had a go at pickling but can't figure out what the `s` is in `query = pickle.loads(s)` from the docs.

Comment: s is a pickle string. Can you just dump the repr() somewhere you can see it? That may give us a hint to debug what your data structure actually looks like.

Comment: Googled `repr()` - is that similar to the `__unicode__` method? I logged the output of that for each item I'm iterating through and it looks as I expect - http://dpaste.com/543602/ (apologies for formatting). Each iteration makes 2 queries to get the type_slug.

Comment: It looks a lot like those results are Django objects rather than simple values. If you're looking just for the type_slug, your SQL should be getting that if you really want to optimize...

Comment: If you're not sure, try looking with type(item).

Comment: Yeah, they are objects. I just can't understand why it's hitting the database again when I loop when I specifically wrote my own SQL to avoid Django doing weird stuff in the background :(

Comment: Because your SQL is getting back Django objects, rather than a simple dictionary. When you do a property lookup on a Django object, it hits the DB if it doesn't already have that (which your SQL probably doesn't do).

Comment: The type(item) for each one is `<class 'cms.models.Media_Deferred_band_id_media_type_id_release_id'>`

Comment: If you don't want Django objects, return a list of values in your SQL.

Comment: Without access to the query you're using, I can't tell you how to change that.

Comment: Well, for starters I sure hope band_id is really well sanitized... ;)

Comment: So what do the actual results for this query look like?

Comment: I wrote my own SQL specifically so I could control my own `JOIN`s and avoid Django doing extra lookups - it's bizarre. If I pass the QuerySet my SQL returns into a view and access the `type_slug` from there, it doesn't run any extra queries.

Comment: That is really weird. I assume the behavior you've been seeing has been the result of trying to do that lookup directly in a template?

Comment: The results are as I expect them to be - I can access them normally within my template. My only issue is that I want to separate the results into categories (rather than make a query for each category) so I can use them in different places in my template without looping through the entire resultset.

Comment: So what exact data structures are you trying to get back with your query? Can you sketch that out?

Comment: Well, I can access them within a template with things like `m.type_slug' or `m.bandname` - they work exactly as I expect - no extra DB requests. Worst comes to the worst I'll just loop through the entire set each time, but I'd rather not.

Comment: You don't actually have a model called "Media_Deferred_band_id_media_type_id_release_id" do you? I assume that's a side effect of the raw query. That looks like it should be a list of IDs that reference objects.

Comment: What do the raw SQL query results for that look like? I think you're not getting back what you think you're getting back.

Comment: Nope, just Media... no idea what that's referring to. This is my first Django project (as may be obvious...) and I'm kinda bummed out that writing straightforward queries seems to be beyond me - I'll just try the uglier looping solution instead - thanks so much for all your help efforts though! Marking you as answer anyway. EDIT: raw SQL is exactly what I want, honestly. I wrote the query in phpMyAdmin first to make sure it returned everything I needed.

Comment: I still think you can probably do this using the built in ORM in an efficient way. I think your query is broken in a non obvious way, but I don't know what the actual SQL results look like to help you troubleshoot it. Turn on the logging and paste it?

Comment: OOOH. Raw isn't really what you want in the first place. It tries to translate that into models, which is the problem. Look at this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Basically, "The raw() manager method can be used to perform raw SQL queries that return model instances." You don't want model instances, you want SQL results. So you want to manipulate the connection directly.

Comment: Okay cool - my brain is fried and I'm approaching sleeptime but I will try this tomorrow - thanks so much for the support.

Comment: Glad to help. I think this will fix your problem. :)