# Django/python: loop through a dictionary and add an item to it

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Apologies for probably simple question, I've read the docs and still can't get this working.

I'm making a raw SQL query in Django which is long so I won't post it here - suffice it to say that it works and returns results.

I want to loop through my query results and check to see if the bandname is of the format "The [band]" and rewrite it to "[band], The". I'm aware I could do this via SQL but the performance isn't great for a large amount of rows, and I have a function on the band model to sort in this way, but can't use it alongside a raw SQL query.

Here is my code:

```
m = Media.objects.raw('SELECT blah FROM foo')

for index, item in enumerate(m):
        if item.bandname_alt:
            if item.bandname_alt[:4] == 'The ':
                m[index].bandname_sortable = item.bandname_alt[4:] + ', The'
```

I know the logic works and finds the right bands, but can't figure out how to add the `bandname_sortable` field to the dictionary so I can access it inside my views.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid raw SQL queries.  They're rarely necessary.  That's a separate question, however.

You have two ways to touch up your results.

**In the model**.  If you can find a way to avoid raw SQL, you can easily add a property to your model to handle this.

```
class Media( models.Model ):
    @property
    def clean_band_name( self ):
        if self.bandname_alt[:4] == 'The ':
            return self.bandname_alt[4:] + ', The'
        else:
            return self.bandname_alt
```

You can use `sorted( list(results), key=lambda x: x.clean_band_name() )`

**In the View**.  Build simple list of tuples or list of named tuples with your expanded results.

```
data = [ (cleanup(item.bandname_alt), item) for item in m ]
```

Since data is a simple sequence it can be sorted by the first element in each tuple.

```
data.sort()
```

Comment: The raw SQL is mainly due to Django making a ton of extra DB calls for each item in my list, despite select_related() and other tweaks - long thread about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037312/django-raw-sql-query-looping-over-result-it-executes-a-query-for-every-iterati - as for the view option - sorry, I don't quite follow - where does the cleanup() function get defined?

Comment: @Matt Andrews.  "Where does the cleanup() function get defined?"  Don't understand the question.  Anywhere.  Same module as the view function is one of many, many choices.  What seems to make sense based on the overall application?

Comment: @Matt Andrews. The related question seems to be a debate the merits of raw SQL without measuring the performance of the actual ORM  alternative that avoids raw SQL.  I'm not sure that's helpful, since it is all based on the (unmeasured) assumption that raw is faster.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification. As for raw SQL, I'm going by sheer number of database queries: 1 versus n*3 (for a list of 100+ items).

Comment: @Matt Andrews. Don't count requests.  Measure the time.  Because of caching, the number of queries isn't a good indicator of anything but network traffic.  Also.  You may be able to simplify the Django ORM processing with a little care.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming as you mentioned that you have a good reason for the raw query. That's fine, perhaps you can instantiate an object of Media for each interation, load in your PK and set your values and run a .save()?